# pocketsphinx android avoid not listed recognition

Tags: android, pocketsphinx

I'm implementing an android app using pocketsphinx. So far I was able to recognize my own grammar and that works almost perfect.

```
#JSGF V1.0;

grammar commands;

public <command> = change colour | display time;
```

And in my code I have

```
    recognizer = SpeechRecognizerSetup.defaultSetup()
                .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "en-us-ptm"))
                .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))
                .setRawLogDir(assetsDir)
                .getRecognizer();
    recognizer.addListener(this);

    File commandsGrammar = new File(assetsDir, "commands.gram");
    recognizer.addGrammarSearch(COMMANDS_SEARCH, commandsGrammar);
```

When I say either `change colour` or `display time`, the hypothesis correctly returns them. However, if I say something outside my grammar, the hypothesis usually returns `change colour` or `display time`. I can say `come right now` (which doesn't belong to my grammar) and the `change colour` is returned in the hypothesis. Is there a way where, if the sentence doesn't exist in my grammar, return `null`?

I also tried using `addKeywordSearch` instead, with a grammar giving the commands a threshold but I think this cannot be done with phrases (only words) because when I tried it, neither of the commands were detected.

```
change colour /1e-1/
display time /1e-1/
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use keyword spotting mode

You can use phrases in keyword spotting, you just need a different threshold like 1e-30.